GPG key for the OpenSUSE Build Service repository
How to get GPG key for the OpenSUSE Build Service repository?
For the error of:
Err:13 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_20.04  InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4D64390375060AA4

I tried:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4D64390375060A
But I'm getting:
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.I8Jw7cEwXe/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 4D64390375060A
gpg: "4D64390375060A" not a key ID: skipping

Is there anywhere, like other key servers, that I can get the GPG key for the OpenSUSE Build Service repository pls?
